# Transform:scale not working properly on grid element

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

A simple grid, with gaps set to 0 shows a small line when I use the transform:scale(1.5) css  property.
Is it some kind of bug os I'm doing something wrong?
Weird that the Firefox result is diffente from chrome result.

If it's not a mistake, but really a bug, any idea how to solve it?

Look at the simple code:

```css
body {
        margin: 40px;
    }

    .wrapper {
        display: grid;
        grid-gap: 0px;
        grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #444;

        transform: scale(1.5);
        transform-origin: 0 0;
    }

    .box {
        background-color: #444;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 0px;
        padding: 20px;
        font-size: 150%;

    }

    .a {
        grid-column: 1 / 3;
        grid-row: 1;
    }
    .b {
        grid-column: 3 ;
        grid-row: 1 / 3;
    }
    .c {
        grid-column: 1 ;
        grid-row: 2 ;
    }
    .d {
        grid-column: 2;
        grid-row: 2;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="box a">A</div>
        <div class="box b">B</div>
        <div class="box c">C</div>
        <div class="box d">D</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to set the font-size on box not on % but in rem, em or px. But anyway it is a scaling problem, causing this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE; Added: backface-visibility: hidden

```css
body {
        margin: 40px;
    }

    .wrapper {
        display: grid;
        grid-gap: 0px;
        grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
        color: #fff;

      
        transform: scale(1.5);
        transform-origin: 0 0;
    }

    .box {
        background-color: #444;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 0px;
        padding: 20px;
        font-size: 150%;
        backface-visibility: hidden;

    }

    .a {
        grid-column: 1 / 3;
        grid-row: 1;
    }
    .b {
        grid-column: 3 ;
        grid-row: 1 / 3;
    }
    .c {
        grid-column: 1 ;
        grid-row: 2 ;
    }
    .d {
        grid-column: 2;
        grid-row: 2;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="grid-wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="box a">A</div>
        <div class="box b">B</div>
        <div class="box c">C</div>
        <div class="box d">D</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually, this is hiding the undesidered line with the same background color of the box. However, imagine that I'm using background images in the boxes. Which background color should I set to the wrapper? Won't solve

Comment: I added backface-visibility: hidden; to the .box and removed bg 444. It likely works

Comment: Amazing! Thanks!